# Use Photoshop Script to create a panel with 3 buttons

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script, photoshop-cs5

I would like to create a panel with 3 buttons:

1. button - add image 1
2. button - add image 2
3. Cancel

---

```
var dlg = new Window( "dialog", "Alert Box Builder" );
dlg.btnPnl = dlg.add( "panel", undefined, "Build it" );
dlg.btnPnl.testBtn = dlg.btnPnl.add( "button", undefined, "Test" );
dlg.btnPnl.buildBtn = dlg.btnPnl.add( "button", undefined, "Build", {name: "ok" } );
dlg.btnPnl.cancelBtn = dlg.btnPnl.add( "button", undefined, "Cancel", { name: "cancel" } );
dlg.show();
```

Comment: I've edited your post to put some context into the title.  It helps to say what technologies you are using there rather than just relying on tags.   I've also reformatted your requirements section with lists which makes it much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track! Doing this just requires adding one more button and then adding a special `onClick` function for the buttons. That function will open up the operating system's file browser and then assign a file to the `pic1File` and `pic2File` variables.

```
#target photoshop
var pic1File;
var pic2File;

var dlg = new Window( "dialog", "Alert Box Builder" );
btnPnl = dlg.add( "panel", undefined, "Build it" );
pic1Btn = btnPnl.add( "button", undefined, "Image 1" );
pic2Btn = btnPnl.add( "button", undefined, "Image 2" );
buildBtn = btnPnl.add( "button", undefined, "Build", {name: "ok" } );
cancelBtn = btnPnl.add( "button", undefined, "Cancel", { name: "cancel" } );

pic1Btn.onClick = function() {
    pic1File = new File;
    pic1File = pic1File.openDlg ( "Select Background Image", "Images: *.png; *.jpeg; *.jpg" )
    if( pic1File != null ) { pic1Btn.text = File.decode ( pic1File.name ) }
    else { 
        pic1File = new File;
        pic1Btn.text = "No file selected";
    }
}

pic2Btn.onClick = function() {
    pic2File = new File;
    pic2File = pic2File.openDlg ( "Select Background Image", "Images: *.png; *.jpeg; *.jpg" )
    if( pic2File != null ) { pic2Btn.text = File.decode ( pic2File.name ) }
    else { 
        pic2File = new File;
        pic2Btn.text = "No file selected";
    }
}

dlg.show();
```

Hope that helps!